# IE 8/7 defect DOM and CSS

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, pagination, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I've just finished [my personal website](http://www.walkap.com). Everything is good with all modern browsers but I have just a little problem with internet explorer 8/7. My website is based on feeds from all my social network all posts are performed with masonry brick and infinite scroll, so the pagination is hidden. In IE the css style disappear just in the first page of my content and masonry doesn't work good until the second page is arrived. Are there anyone who can help me to find the error? IE doesn't serve useful tools to check it out so I need someone helps me please!!! Thanks to every one!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your formatting is broken in Internet Explorer 7 and 8 is because you're using the [`article` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg593005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); which isn't natively understood in versions of Internet Explorer prior to 9.

I dropped in the [HTML5Shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) (which creates some support for HTML5 elements) and refreshed your page - it solved the issue(s).